# How do i generate a fresh access token from a stale token in django-allauth?

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

I have integrated allauth in my django project and users are able to log in via their facebook accounts. Now their tokens are available in the database but when i use them to get data of the users from facebook it results in an error that token has expired.
So what i want to ask:

1. Does/Can django-allauth update the tokens when users log into my site?
2. If it can/does this then how can i get a fresh token without having my users go through the login flow(maybe fake a login flow)?

Sidenote about 2:
I searched on facebook docs regarding this and they provide a method to refresh tokens via a GET call:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
client_id={app-id}&
client_secret={app-secret}&
fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

but this must be done before the token expires while i am using tokens in a cron script to get data so this won't work for me.

Comment: An expired token isn't good for anything. If you could use it to get a valid token, it'd defeat the purpose of having it expire at all.

Comment: @user2357112 : that is what i am asking. Is there any way to get fresh tokens?

Comment: `how can i get a fresh token without having my users go through the login flow` - NOT possible!

Comment: @Shadowfax : any workaround?

Comment: What's your requirement? Why do you need the long-lived token?

Comment: @Shadowfax: i have a cron script to get the data from profiles and for that i need access tokens. I run the script once a day so when the script runs all the tokens have expired.

Comment: Then the user has to come again and visit your site, once in every 60 days at least.

Answer (score 1):

A typical User Access Token is valid for 2 hours, you can extend it to 60 days. But you cannot refresh a Token without user interaction. Else, it would make no sense to limit the validity. Which is an important feature, if a user does not use an app for some days, the app should not be able to use his token anymore.

So, you cannot refresh the Token with a cron job. The user has to refresh it (FB.getLoginStatus in the JavaScript SDK, for example).

More about Access Tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/